# How to create exam sheets with solutions in a non-English language with R exams

Tags: r-exams

In order to create the exam sheets without solution, everything works fine with `exams2nops` (apart from the logo which is not taken for some reason). I can add the name of the institution, change the title, and setup a non-English language and the date. But if I want to create examsheets with the solutions, then, if I understand correctly, I cannot use anymore `exams2nops`, but I have to use `exams2pdf` with `template="solution"` which does not take into account the institution, the date, the language, nor the title. 
Any help?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site (and to R/exams). You are correct that the complete solution cannot be shown with `exams2nops`. But in order to give a recommendation it would be helpful to better understand your intended use-case: How many students will participate in the exam? Will each student receive their own random version of the exam? What do you need the solution for - for the teacher or the student?

Comment: Thank you! At least 130 students will partecipate to the exam, but it's possible that they will be more. Since it's the very first time that I use R exams, my intention is, for this time, to use just 10 random version of the exam. The solution is useful for me to be able to do grading manually, in case grading does not work by scanning, but I also would like to let each student have the solution after the exam (I'll try to send each student a personalized emai through R, otherwise I'll post the 10 solutions on Moodle).

Comment: Which "solution" do you want to share? Just which boxes needed to be checked? Or the complete solution environment with the complete answer text? The former is part of the standard `nops_eval()` output, the latter would necessitate producing dedicated solutions via `exams2pdf()` or `exams2html()` with the same random seed. Re: scanning. I would recommend that you do a trial exam (yourself or with some colleagues) and then play around with your scanner settings so that `nops_scan()` works reliably.

Comment: I meant the complete solution environment with the complete answer text. But I have found out how to obtain what I wanted (i.e. the exam sheet with solutions in non English language). To achieve this, I just took the file "solutions" from the R directory in "Documents" and I have translated what is written inside.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the follow-up, that would have been my recommended solution for that setup. I'll write it up in an answer so that you can mark the question as answered here on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that `exams2nops()` does not provide a version of the PDF with the `{solution}` environment and the complete answer text. The `nops_eval()` only provides a HTML report with the correct boxes that needed to be checked.

So to produce a PDF as desired you can run `exams2pdf(...)` or `exams2pdf(..., type = "solution")` after setting the same random seed that you set before running `exams2nops()`. If you want to modify anything like layout/logo/language/etc. in `exams2pdf()` you have full flexibility but need to do the work yourself. That is you need to come up with a LaTeX template file that looks the way you want. As a starting point you can take `solution.tex` from the package. The easiest way to get all templates shipped with the package is to run `exams_skeleton()` and then look at the templates folder.

Background info: `exams2nops()` also just calls `exams2pdf()` internally after setting up a suitable LaTeX template file based on the arguments specified by the user.